# Combine multiple plots, generated using the "by" R function, in one figure

Tags: r, plot, grouping

I have a data frame containing multiple numeric columns and one column with different factors. I'd like to produce a unique image containing the plots of the numeric columns, by factor. I tried the following:

```
varA    <- runif(40)
varB    <- runif(40)
varB    <- runif(40)
varC    <- runif(40)

mainVar <- c(rep('cat', 10), rep('dof', 10), rep('mouse', 10), rep('frog', 10))

plotData <- data.frame(varA, varB, varC, mainVar)

pdf('asd.pdf')
par(mfrow=c(2,2))

by(plotData, plotData$mainVar, function(x){

  par(mfrow=c(1,3))
  boxplot(x$varA)
  boxplot(x$varB)
  boxplot(x$varC)

})

dev.off()
```

It produces a unique pdf, but with a page for every factor.

Instead, I'd like to get something like that (without the red lines):

[image: figure]

Comment: You can't nest `par(mar=...)` like that. You'll likely need to do more manual work, perhaps with `layout` or using `ggplot2` and a `facet_*` function.

Comment: As Gregor pointed out, that was intended to read *"you can't nest `par(mfrow=...)`"*.

Answer (score 3):

First, both techniques shown here prefer data in a "tall" format. There are several tools that will reshape it for you, I'll use

```
# library(tidyr)
plotDataTall <- tidyr::gather(plotData, k, v, -mainVar)
head(plotDataTall)
#   mainVar    k         v
# 1     cat varA 0.4023846
# 2     cat varA 0.3406813
# 3     cat varA 0.7990530
# 4     cat varA 0.3706167
# 5     cat varA 0.5986029
# 6     cat varA 0.1626782
```

Other tools include the `reshape2` package or the stats function `reshape`, both of which are increasingly less-intuitive to use for first time users.

### `ggplot2`

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(plotDataTall, aes(x = k, y = v)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~ mainVar, nrow=2) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank())
```

[image: faceted boxplot]

## Base R

Because you cannot nest uses of `par(mfrow=...)` (they replace, not nest), you can stick with the over-arching 2x2 and handling the per-variable boxplots within boxplot. This can be with the wide data:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2), mar=c(4,3,3,0.1))
ign <- by(plotData, plotData$mainVar, function(x) {
  boxplot(x$varA, x$varB, x$varC, main=x$mainVar[1])
})
```

or the tall format:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2), mar=c(4,3,3,0.1))
ign <- by(plotDataTall, plotDataTall$mainVar, function(x) {
  boxplot(v~k, data=x, main=x$mainVar[1])
})
```

(I took the liberty of adjusting the `mar`gins, primarily for a shrunken combined plot here. Not required for production.)

[image: base R boxplots]

Comment: @Gregor, sorry, but I don't understand. I used both `mfrow` and `mar` correctly, and said why I changed the margins. If you're suggesting that the `mar=` is unnecessary, I wholeheartedly agree ... and commented as such. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Oh, of course, I see the typo. Thanks. (Perhaps it was the `g` in `gsub` that threw me ... \*shrug\*)

Comment: That would have done it for me. Moot now. Thanks for the QA, Gregor.

Answer (score 0):

As r2evans already points out, I doubt this is possible with the base plot function. Using ggplot2 (part of the tidyverse) you can get a one-page plot using:

```
library(tidyverse)
plotData %>% 
gather(var, y, -mainVar) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = var, y = y)) + geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap(~mainVar)
```

note that this also uses the pipe operator (dplyr), and gather (tidyr) both part of tidyverse